# Remove some text from a filename on save

Tags: c#

Ok what I am doing is selecting a file name and saving the filename only. What I need to do is remove certain text from it but it changes and that's the issue I am having.

The main one is it has name_zm and I want to remove _zm from the name.

But some other files have ak47_fmg_mp and all i want is the first before the _

but not sure how to accomplish this.

I have tried text replace `regex` even but none of it has worked

```
            string result = nyu_res.filename;
            result = result.Replace("_zm", "");
```

Well when i select a file it saves the filename in this example. Lets say I selected 
m14_zm

What I want to do is get m14 and thats it. Same with the others. Just want to get to the first '_'. I tried the code above but could not get it to work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: meet my friends `Substring` and `IndexOf`. They'll help you get the job done.

Answer (score 2):

Use Split('_') and take the first one.
Then you don't have to check if it contains _ or not.

```
result = result.Split('_')[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your string for Null/Empty and '_' then you can use Substring and IndexOf to do that :

```
var result = "fileName_zm";
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) && result.Contains('_'))
{
    result = result.Substring(0, result.IndexOf("_"));
}
```

Advantage: if string is Null/Empty it will short circuit and you will save few cycles of CPU.

Comment: You should check first if result is not null or empty, and that it actually contains `_`.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Done in the edit, i think of it just after my answer

Comment: @elfenliedtopfan5 Validate one of the answer if you have your solution, https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers